# Get IN and OUT date from booking table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example I have this kind of table

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|      ID      |     USER    |   READER    |         DATETIME        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1      |      1      |   READER1   | 2020-01-14 08:12:43.000 |
|       1      |      1      |   READER2   | 2020-01-14 08:13:12.000 |
|       1      |      1      |   READER2   | 2020-01-14 10:12:19.000 |
|       1      |      1      |   READER1   | 2020-01-14 10:13:23.000 |
|       1      |      1      |   READER1   | 2020-01-14 10:30:43.000 |
|       1      |      1      |   READER1   | 2020-01-14 11:30:43.000 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the IN and OUT date of a user per reader

Example :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    USER    |    READER    |             IN            |             OUT           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1     |    READER1   |  2020-01-14 08:12:43.000  |  2020-01-14 10:13:23.000  |
|      1     |    READER2   |  2020-01-14 08:13:12.000  |  2020-01-14 10:12:19.000  |
|      1     |    READER1   |  2020-01-14 10:30:43.000  |  2020-01-14 11:30:43.000  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How could I get this result?

Comment: What if there are more than two records per user, how many records to you want in the resultset? Extending your sample data with a few more records might make ie more representative.

Comment: We're keen to help, the keyword being help - not do it all for you. So show us what you tried and where you got stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to group every two records of the same user/reader. You can use `row_number()` and `lead()` for this:

```
select usr, reader, datetime [in], lead_datetime [out]
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by usr, reader order by datetime) rn,
        lead(datetime) over(partition by usr, reader order by datetime) lead_datetime
    from mytable t
) t
where rn % 2 = 1
order by [in]
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6342ac2d5d6bb71dce8a5f2aa09c7235)**:

```
usr | reader  | in                  | out                
--: | :------ | :------------------ | :------------------
  1 | READER1 | 2020-01-14 08:12:43 | 2020-01-14 10:13:23
  1 | READER2 | 2020-01-14 08:13:12 | 2020-01-14 10:12:19
  1 | READER1 | 2020-01-14 10:30:43 | 2020-01-14 11:30:43
```